# Is it possible to port an iOS application to Android?

Tags: java, android, ios, xcode

I created an application with xCode and Objective-C for iOS. What is the best way to create an android app similar to the iOS one?

Is there any application for the same purpose?

My app has dependencies of

- Calayer
- Bizerpath
- App delegate and protocols
- Run time blur

Comment: rewrite it in java for android - that´s it! or use some of the ... cross-mobile frameworks like cordova, phonegap, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

absolutely not
because they are 2 different thing

i think you have to write android version from scratch

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the app for Android.

An alternative is to use a tool, like https://code.google.com/p/objc2j/

http://objc2j.googlecode.com/svn/

I did not try it. Anyway, if you use the tool, then make sure you test all the features. It might be cheaper to rewrite it, but this is a management issue.